# JavaScript object shorthands

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring, spread-syntax, rest-parameters

I have this clunky code here and hope there is any way to shorten this.
By the way, "req.query" is my query object from an nodejs express server.

```
    const q = req.query

    User.insertOne({
        firstName: q.firstName,
        lastName: q.lastName,
        bestFriend: q.bestFriend,
        hobbies: q.hobbies,
        address: {
            street: q.address.street,
            number: q.address.number,
            plz: q.address.plz,
            city: q.address.city,
            country: q.address.country,
        },
        contact: {
            telephone: q.contact.telephone,
            email: q.contact.email,
        },
    })
```

My first solution was - as you can see - to replace req.query with q, but this does not seem to be enough.

Maybe you could do this with the "with" statement, but i haven't used it before and I've heard that you shouldn't implement it (don't know why....).

Comment: `replace req.query with q, but this does not seem to be enough` Why?

Comment: *"but this does not seem to be enough"* - Enough **what**, specifically?  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  I don't see anything particularly wrong with the code shown, is it not working in some way?  If the goal is just to shorten the code... What specifically is the code doing in the first place?  Does each individual property really need to be specified, or are you just looking for a way to clone an object in JavaScript?  Something else?

Comment: What does `insertOne` do? Is there a reason you can't directly insert `req.query`? If there is, you'll probably want to look into deep cloning objects in JS.

Comment: My understanding is that you don't want *all* the fields in `req.query` to be used, and that is why you are individually specifying them all in `insertOne`. Is that correct?

Comment: Why not `User.insertOne(req.query)`?

Comment: well, i use destructuring syntax like {a, b, c} very often where you can easily merge keys and values, but in my case it does not work that way because of the object. i want to look it clean and as short as possible, so i search for some kind of abbrevation syntax. and i know how to clone objects. i do not want to pass the whole req.query object in insertOne directly, because i only want specific keys of the query to be used in this function (like @caTS understood very well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading your title I understood you want to use ES6 object property shorthand. To achieve that in your current setup you would also need to use object destructuring, here's the code:

```
//Object destructuring:
const { firstName, lastName, bestFriend, hobbies } = req.query;
const { street, number, plz, city, country } = req.query.address;
const { telephone, email } = req.query.contact;

//Using the ES6 object property shorthand:
    User.insertOne({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        bestFriend,
        hobbies,
        address: {
            street,
            number,
            plz,
            city,
            country,
        },
        contact: {
            telephone,
            email,
        },
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the property names matches with each other, you can directly assign them in javascript and the relevant properties will be mapped.

```
const q = req.query
User.insertOne(q);
```

If the properties don't match, use spread operator ( ... ) from ES6 which comes handy while mapping objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lodash library and use a the pick method.You only need to specify the names of the fields that you want from req.query,and it'll return an object containing those values which you can use.

```
const _ = require("lodash");  
User.insertOne(_.pick(req.query, [
  "firstName",
  "lastName",
  "bestFriend",
  "hobbies",
  "address.street",
  "address.number",
  "address.plz",
  "address.city",
  "address.country",
  "contact.telephone",
  "contact.email"
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the OP's task was about passing just a subset of the queried data into the method (but actually not just for that) then the OP might have a look into the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax, into the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as well as into the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax.

```js
const req = {
  query: {
    foo: 'Foo',
    bar: 'Bar',

    firstName: 'Anni',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    bestFriend: 'Jane Doe',
    hobbies: '',
    address: {
        street: 'Any Lane',
        number: 42,
        plz: '1-234-456',
        city: 'Some City',
        country: 'Motherland',
    },
    contact: {
        telephone: '9-87-654-321',
        email: 'anni.smith@provider.com',
    },
    more_not_needed_data: {
      baz: 'Baz',
      biz: 'Biz',
    },
  },
};

const userDataFromRest =
  (({ foo, bar, more_not_needed_data, ...data }) => data)(req.query);

const explicitUserData = (
  ({
    firstName, lastName, bestFriend, hobbies, address, contact,
  }) => ({
    firstName, lastName, bestFriend, hobbies, address, contact,
  })
)(req.query);

/*
User
  .insertOne((({ foo, bar, 'more not needed data', ...data }) => data)(req.query));

User
  .insertOne((
    ({
      firstName, lastName, bestFriend, hobbies, address, contact,
    }) => ({
      firstName, lastName, bestFriend, hobbies, address, contact,
    })
  )(req.query));
*/

console.log({
  query: req.query,
  userDataFromRest,
  explicitUserData,  
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```